# Flutter integration tests, with FlutterFire, unable to connect when trying to run for Firebase Test Lab

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, integration-testing, firebase-test-lab

I have a Flutter app (using version 2.5.1) that

- Runs on a simulator
- Run on a physical iOS device
- Runs when I distribute it using TestFlight
- Has integration tests, that run just fine on the simulator.

The app uses Flutterfire and the integration tests uses parts of the app that use Flutterfire.

However, when I follow [these instructions](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/integration_test#ios-device-testing) in order to create something that can eventually be distributed to Firebase Test Lab, I stumble on the penultimate step:

`xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun "build/ios_integ/Build/Products/Runner_iphoneos15.0-arm64-armv7.xctestrun" -destination id=<MYDEVICEID>`

The app deploys to the physical device, and starts to run, but seems to fail to connect to any Firebase back-ends.

The logs have errors that look like those below.

Any pointers as to how I can fix this will be much appreciated!

```
Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2021-09-23 18:50:58.044
Test Suite 'RunnerTests.xctest' started at 2021-09-23 18:50:58.045
Test Suite 'RunnerTests' started at 2021-09-23 18:50:58.045
Test Case '-[RunnerTests testIntegrationTest]' started.
2021-09-23 18:50:58.047998+0100 Runner[404:7739] flutter: 00:00 +0: Porridge (setUpAll)
2021-09-23 18:50:58.049466+0100 Runner[404:7739] flutter: 00:00 +1: Porridge Create User
2021-09-23 18:50:58.052143+0100 Runner[404:7734] 8.6.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.8.6.0 started
2021-09-23 18:50:58.052457+0100 Runner[404:7734] 8.6.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To disable debug logging set the following
application argument: -noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2021-09-23 18:50:58.062413+0100 Runner[404:7730] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection r
efused]
2021-09-23 18:50:58.062759+0100 Runner[404:7730] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1.2:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection r
efused]
2021-09-23 18:50:58.063110+0100 Runner[404:7730] Connection 1: received failure notification
2021-09-23 18:50:58.063199+0100 Runner[404:7730] Connection 1: failed to connect 1:61, reason -1
2021-09-23 18:50:58.063314+0100 Runner[404:7730] Connection 1: encountered error(1:61)
2021-09-23 18:50:58.063936+0100 Runner[404:7730] Task <0B92B415-FE63-4467-8248-8FB5B411688A>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error co
de: -1004 [1:61])
2021-09-23 18:50:58.064589+0100 Runner[404:7730] Task <0B92B415-FE63-4467-8248-8FB5B411688A>.<1> finished with error [-1004] Error Dom
ain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x281c31890
{Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErr
orFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <0B92B415-FE63-4467-8248-8FB5B411688A>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <0B92B415-FE63-4467-8248-8FB5B411688A>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:9099/www.googleapis.com/identi
tytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=AIzaSyCHkqtqAXDFllu7SmuwSw8_pudpAn-dzdM, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:9099/www.go
ogleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=AIzaSyCHkqtqAXDFllu7SmuwSw8_pudpAn-dzdM, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2021-09-23 18:50:58.065318+0100 Runner[404:7739] flutter: [firebase_auth/network-request-failed] Network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
2021-09-23 18:50:58.065511+0100 Runner[404:7739] flutter: #0      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:272)
...etc....
```

Comment: Hey Jon, I'm noticing that the URL string seems to be concatenating localhost with the url you're trying to connect to (the Identity API from Google, if I'm not mistaken), so it's quite possible that that is the cause of this error or that it's covering up the error that's preventing you from loading, can you confirm whether or not changing that gives a different error?

Comment: Ah - nice observation @fabc - I wonder what's causing that `http://localhost:9099/www.googleapis.com/identi
tytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?.....`. I wonder if it's because I had an emulator running. I will try without the emulator.

Comment: Thank you @fabc - I got to the root of my problem.  I had a test `setupAll` that included a setup for the local emulator.  Which doesn't make sense if I'm going to run the tests remotely.  After removing it, all is well. (Of course, now the tests run against my production Firebase database, which may not be ideal, but at least I'll have tests).  Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Thank you for replying and letting me know it worked.